# How to validate the combination of values in two different TextBoxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can i validate them with combination Like PropertyNumber and OwnerNumber combination should not exist in database. Right now i am using `IDataErrorInfo` but it only validates one value at a time.

```
       <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="Auto" Height="16"/>

       <TextBox  Name="PropertyNumber" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Text="{Binding 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay, Path=SelectedPropertyNumber, 
        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Width="115"  Height="22" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsEnabled="{Binding 
        PropertyNumbersEnabled,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />

       <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top" Width="Auto" Height="16"/>

       <TextBox Name="OwnerNumber" Text="{Binding BindingGroupName=NGLDataFormGrp, 
        Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
        Path=OwnerNumber}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Width="115" Height="22"  IsEnabled="{Binding 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
        Path=OwnerNumberEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: How are validating using IdataError..? Please publish that code which helps to give best solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution but it works for me.  The way I usually handle this is create a DataTrigger binded to a boolean property which indicates valid or invalid.

If the boolean is false, I style the border red.  If not, no border color.

Here's an example DataTrigger:

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
     <Setter Property="TextElement.FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
     <Setter Property="TextElement.FontSize" Value="14" />
     <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="Black" />
     <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Value="False">
           <Setter Property="Effect">
              <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Color="Red" ShadowDepth="0" />
              </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
           <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Message Field entered does not exist in Message Output tree." />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsValid}" Value="True">
           <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{x:Null}" />
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

If you apply this style to both of our textboxes bound to the same boolean, they'll both appear with a glow red border when the boolean is false.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `BindingGroup` for that. Vincent Sibal has a great blog entry about that: [BindingGroups with Item-level Validation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2008/08/11/wpf-3-5-sp1-feature-bindinggroups-with-item-level-validation.aspx).

Comment: Thanks XAMeLi, I was unaware of BindingGroup.  With XAML, you learn something everyday.